# enum underlying type vs normal type

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

If i try to compile below code it will give me error that 'enumerator value too large for underlying type 'char'

```
enum class Status:char{one=126,two=127,three=128};
Status s = Status::three;
```

However if i execute following code compiler don't give me any errors and silently ignores that char upper range is crossed

```
char x = 128;
```

So is there any specific reason why compiler don't check in case of normal data type and check for range in case of enum underlying type.

Comment: For backward compatible I guess. And if this were not allowed you may feel quite annoying converting the returned `int` of APIs like `getchar()` or `istream::get()` to `char`.

Comment: Looks like `char` is signed in your implementation. Its values probably range from -128 to 127. 128 would overflow the `char`, but is not ill-formed. Note that signed overflow is undefined behavior. I guess it's ill-formed to have a constant with an undefined value, though.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? gcc-6.1 says `error: enumerator value 128 is outside the range of underlying type ‘char’`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 introduced restrictions on "narrowing conversions" and where they are and aren't allowed. Tucked away in 5.19§3 is a clause that describes "converted constant expression"s and specifically precludes narrowing conversions, and then notes that such expressions may be used in [...] enumerator initializers. Thus, you can't do:

```
enum class Foo : char { one = 128 };
unsigned char uc1 = {-1};
```

but you can do

```
enum class Foo : char { one = (char)128 };
unsigned char uc1 = -1;
```

5.19 [expr.const] §3

> [...] A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to a prvalue of type T, where the converted expression is a core constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only user-defined conversions, lvalue-torvalue conversions (4.1), integral promotions (4.5), and integral conversions (4.7) other than narrowing conversions (8.5.4). [ Note: such expressions may be used in new expressions (5.3.4), as case expressions (6.4.2), as enumerator initializers if the underlying type is fixed (7.2), as array bounds (8.3.4), and as integral or enumeration non-type template arguments (14.3). —end note ]